# Primary menu not showing when lanugage is changed?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I have installed following modules :

1.Locale
2.Content Translation
3.Internationalization
4.Block translation
5.CCK translation
6.Content type translation 7.Menu  translation

I added Arabic language .po file using admin/build/translate/import. I added one menu item for English and another menu item for Arabic in primary links. The menu items added for English are displayed on a node view page (when English is selected from language switcher) but the menu items added for Arabic are not displayed on a node view page (when Arabic is selected from language switcher).

Answer (score 1):

Since Menu items are user created the Locale module cannot translate them all.. You have to manually create translation for each menu item for both the languages and it maps according to the language.